# passing values between two pages wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I am learning c# and I have been asked to work on a project using WPF, which I don't know much. We are using MUI as well.
I am trying to achieve a pretty basic task. I have two pages called `ClientRNG.xaml`and `ServerRNG.xaml`. In `ClientRNG.xaml` I have two buttons and two textfield, when each button is pressed a random number is generated and it appears in a text box. In `ServerRNG` there are just one button and one textfield, with the same functionality as mentioned above.
So I'll end up with three different random numbers, one in `ServerRNG.xaml` and two in `ClientRNG`.
What i want to do is to pass these random numbers to another page called `SSL.xaml`.

The pages are created in `MainWindow.xml`:

```
<mui:ModernWindow.MenuLinkGroups>
    <mui:LinkGroup DisplayName="network security">
        <mui:LinkGroup.Links>
            <mui:Link DisplayName="Home" Source="/Pages/Home.xaml" />
            <mui:Link DisplayName="RNG" Source="/Pages/ClientRNG.xaml" />
            <mui:Link DisplayName="3DES" Source="/Pages/3des.xaml" />
            <mui:Link DisplayName="RSA" Source="/Pages/RSA.xaml" />
            <mui:Link DisplayName="SHA-1" Source="/Pages/sha1.xaml" />
            <mui:Link DisplayName="PKI Certificates" Source="/Pages/pki.xaml" />
            <mui:Link DisplayName="SSL" Source="/Pages/SSL.xaml" />

        </mui:LinkGroup.Links>
    </mui:LinkGroup>
    <mui:LinkGroup DisplayName="settings" GroupName="settings">
        <mui:LinkGroup.Links>
            <mui:Link DisplayName="software" Source="/Pages/Settings.xaml" />
        </mui:LinkGroup.Links>
    </mui:LinkGroup>
</mui:ModernWindow.MenuLinkGroups>

<mui:ModernWindow.TitleLinks>
    <mui:Link DisplayName="settings" Source="/Pages/Settings.xaml" />
</mui:ModernWindow.TitleLinks>
```

Code in ClientRNG:

```
namespace NetworkSecuritySSLTest.Pages
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for RNG.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class ClientRNG : UserControl
{
    public ClientRNG()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Random r = new Random(1);
        int number = r.Next(0, 100);
        r1Out.Text = number.ToString();
        SharingManager.GlobalValue = number;
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Random r = new Random(3);
        int number = r.Next(0, 100);
        pmsOutC.Text = number.ToString();
    }
```

here is the code I have in ServerRNG:

```
namespace NetworkSecuritySSLTest.Pages
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for RNG.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class ServerRNG : UserControl
{

    private SplitPage1 sp;



    public ServerRNG()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Random r = new Random(2);
        int number = r.Next(0, 100);
        r2Out.Text = number.ToString();
        SharingManager.GlobalValue = number;
    }
}
```

}

and this is the code behind `SSL` class

```
namespace NetworkSecuritySSLTest.Pages
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for SplitPage1.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class SplitPage1 : UserControl
{
    private int r1FromClient;
    public SplitPage1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SharingManager.ValueChanged += UpdateTextBox1;
        SharingManager.ValueChanged += UpdateTextBox2;

    }

    public void UpdateTextBox1(object sender, NumericEventArgs e)
    {
        r1SSLBox.Text = e.Value.ToString(); // Update textBox
    }

    public void UpdateTextBox2(object sender, NumericEventArgs e)
    {
        r2SSLBox.Text = e.Value.ToString(); // Update textBox
    }

}
```

}
here are the xaml:
     'SplitPage1'

```
<UserControl x:Class="NetworkSecuritySSLTest.Pages.SplitPage1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignWidth="766.507" Height="535">
<Grid Style="{StaticResource ContentRoot}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="6"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="CLIENT" Style="{StaticResource Heading2}" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="hello" Text="Hello Server. This is my Random Number and my Security Capabilities:" FontSize="12" FontStyle="Italic" Margin="0,10,0,0" UseLayoutRounding="False" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="helloCont" Text="" FontSize="12" FontStyle="Italic" Margin="0,0,0,0"  />
            <TextBox x:Name ="r1SSLBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="57" Margin="10,88,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" RenderTransformOrigin="0.498,0.404"/>
            <TextBox x:Name ="r2SSLBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="57" Margin="10,88,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" RenderTransformOrigin="0.498,0.404"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="VerifyDC" Text="I need to verify your Digital Certificate:" FontSize="12" FontStyle="Italic" Margin="0,10,0,0"  />
            <TextBlock x:Name="VerifyCont" Text="" FontSize="12" FontStyle="Italic"  />

            <TextBlock x:Name="MSK" Text="My Master Key is:" FontSize="12" FontStyle="Italic" Margin="0,10,0,0"  />
            <TextBlock x:Name="MSKCont" Text="" FontSize="12" FontStyle="Italic"  />

        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" />
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="2 " Margin="{StaticResource SplitRight}">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="SERVER" Style="{StaticResource Heading2}" />
            <TextBlock Text="Content goes here" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <GridSplitter Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,23,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="735"/>
    <Button Content="Man-In-The-Middle-Attack" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="209" RenderTransformOrigin="0.055,0.397" Height="40" Margin="255,451,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />

</Grid>
```

ClientRNG

```
<UserControl x:Class="NetworkSecuritySSLTest.Pages.ClientRNG"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignWidth="766.507" Height="535">
<Viewbox Stretch="None">
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource ContentRoot}" Height="301" Margin="0" Width="435">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- TODO: set @SelectedSource -->

        <mui:ModernTab Layout="Tab" Margin="0,52,0,0">
            <mui:ModernTab.Links>
                <!-- TODO: set @Source -->
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Client" />
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Server" Source="/Pages/ServerRNG.xaml"  />
            </mui:ModernTab.Links>
        </mui:ModernTab>

        <Button Content="GENERATE R# 1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.055,0.397" Height="26" Margin="10,52,0,0" FontSize="11" Click="Button_Click" />
        <TextBox Name ="r1Out" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="57" Margin="10,88,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" RenderTransformOrigin="0.498,0.404"/>

        <Button Content="GENERATE MS" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="119"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.055,0.397" Height="26" Margin="306,52,0,0" Click="Button_Click_2" />
        <TextBox Name ="msOutC" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="57" Margin="306,88,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="119" RenderTransformOrigin="0.498,0.404"/>

        <Button Content="GENERATE PMS" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="133"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.055,0.397" Height="26" Margin="151,52,0,0" Click="Button_Click_1" />
        <TextBox Name ="pmsOutC" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="57" Margin="151,88,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="133" RenderTransformOrigin="0.498,0.404"/>


        <Label Content="Random Number Generator" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="19" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="415" FontWeight="Bold"/>


    </Grid>

</Viewbox>
```

and `ServerRNG`

```
<UserControl x:Class="NetworkSecuritySSLTest.Pages.ServerRNG"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignWidth="766.507" Height="535">
<Viewbox Stretch="None">
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource ContentRoot}" Height="301" Margin="0" Width="435">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- TODO: set @SelectedSource -->

        <mui:ModernTab Layout="Tab" Margin="0,52,0,0">
            <mui:ModernTab.Links>
                <!-- TODO: set @Source -->
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Client" Source="/Pages/ClientRNG.xaml" />
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Server" />
            </mui:ModernTab.Links>
        </mui:ModernTab>

        <Button Name ="r2but" Content="GENERATE R# 2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.055,0.397" Height="26" Margin="76,52,0,0" FontSize="11" Click="Button_Click_1" />
        <TextBox Name ="r2Out" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="57" Margin="76,88,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" RenderTransformOrigin="0.498,0.404"/>

        <Button Content="GENERATE MS" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="119"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.055,0.397" Height="26" Margin="249,52,0,0" />
        <TextBox Name ="msOutS" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="57" Margin="249,88,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="119" RenderTransformOrigin="0.498,0.404"/>


        <Label Content="Random Number Generator" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="19" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="415" FontWeight="Bold"/>


    </Grid>

</Viewbox>
```

Now I was trying to use the solution posted by Omribitan but i am still struggling

Comment: How are you **showing** `SplitPage1` ? in the code you posted you are just instansiating it ...

Comment: you will have to share the xaml to tell the relation between two usercontrol. are they siblings or there is a parent child relation?

Comment: @nit they are siblings, sorry I haven't code the xaml someone else did it

Comment: @Omribitan the splitpage1 is the one that is showed at the beginning

Comment: @nit I added the two xaml

Comment: it seems I am not calling 'showing()' method anywhere... but I can see the page. Sorry guys i am really new about this..

Answer (score 1):

According to what you said in the comment section that `SplitPage1` is already shown,

What you are doing in your code is creating a **new** instance of `SplitPage1` and passing it your data

```
    SplitPage1 sp = new SplitPage1(); // This is a new page, not the one currently shown in your application
    sp.Setr1SSLBox(number); // it should set the text box in SSL page
```

So if you want to set the text of the currently displayed `SplitPage1`, you need to get it's reference. It's hard to say how because I can't see your entire code but this is what I would consider:

1. Using [IoC container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921087.aspx) to resolve the current instance of `SplitPage1`.
2. According to your code seems like there is a third party creating these pages. If that's true, it could pass `ServerRNG` a reference of the `SplitPage1` it's creating which you'll be able to use later, for example :

   ```
   public partial class ServerRNG : UserControl
   {
        private SplitPage1 sp;

        public ServerRNG(SplitPage1 splitPage) : this()
        {
             sp = splitPage; // Save a reference to the currently displayed `SplitPage1` page
        }

        public ServerRNG()
        {
             InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
               Random r = new Random(2);
               int number = r.Next(0, 100);
               r2Out.Text = number.ToString();
               sp.Setr1SSLBox(number); // Set the correct instance's text
        }
   }
   ```
3. Create a class which will expose a static property and event that will fire when that property changes:

   ```
   public class SharingManager
   {
       // Define a global static event to be fired when the value is changing
       public static event EventHandler<NumericEventArgs> ValueChanged;

       public static int GlobalValue
       {
           set
           {
               // Fire ValueChanged event
               if (ValueChanged != null)
                   ValueChanged(null, new NumericEventArgs(value));
            }
        }
     }

    public class NumericEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
       public NumericEventArgs(int value)
       {
           Value = value;
        }

        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
   ```

Register a handler in `SplitPage1`

```
public SplitPage1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SharingManager.ValueChanged += UpdateTextBox;

    }

public void UpdateTextBox(object sender, NumericEventArgs e)
{
    r1SSLBox.Text = e.Value.ToString(); // Update textBox
}
```

In `Button_Click_1` on `ServerNRG`, update the value to fire the event

```
    Random r = new Random(2);
    int number = r.Next(0, 100);
    r2Out.Text = number.ToString();
    SharingManager.GlobalValue = number;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I had similar solution before, however both mine and yours get this error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". it refers to `sp` variable... do i have to call `ServerRNG(SplitPage1 splitPage) somewhere?

Comment: I forgot to mention that we are using `mui`... I don't know if that helps <mui:Link DisplayName="SSL" Source="/Pages/SSL.xaml" /> is the link that leads to splitPage1

Comment: @lucaConfa yes of course, like I said if there is a third party creating this classes it will have to create `ServerRNG` using `ServerRNG(SplitPage1 splitPage)` constructor instead of it's default constructor.

Comment: ok thank you. it seems that I can't find that third party though. Maybe I can't explain my issue properly, sorry

Comment: @lucaConfa By your comment seems like the xaml is creating the class. I updated my answer with a third generic solution that should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your time. It is actually working! Now I'll need to pass other values, hopefully the use of static won't affect the "first" value I have already passed..

Comment: @lucaConfa You shouldn't just "Hope", you should understand :). Notice that `SplitPage1` is accessing the value through the `args` provided by the event, and not accessing a static property. This will mean that each time the `ValueChanged` event is fired a **new** value would be supplied to the handler. If you wish to maintain the previous value you will need to store it somewhere. If you are new to the events concept you can read about it more in the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx). If this answer solved your poblem please mark it as accepted :)

Comment: I am not sure I am doing the right thing... say now I have two textboxes in my splitpage, and each one is getting the value from different pages. Should I have `UpdateSecondTextBox()` method?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39583/discussion-between-omribitan-and-lucaconfa)

Answer (score 0):

you should work on WPF using the MVVM design pattern.
Its kinda annoying without MVVM framework
I suggest you to use http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/

use this tutorial to get started

http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/01/12/caliburn-micro-part-1-getting-started/

it also explains how to use the mediator pattern (using caliburn micros event aggerator) to pass values/commands between diffrent windows.

http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/2/1/caliburn-micro-part-4-the-event-aggregator/